# Experience using F1 License for first line workers

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing

We are planning to use Microsoft F1 licence for first line workers.

Has anyone implemented it for their first line workers?

What is SharePoint Online Kiosk?

Comment: Can you describe how would your first line workers use Microsoft 365? What services are you planning to use? Yammer, SharePoint, Teams, etc?

Comment: goal was to have tablets in terminal, where f1 user can report accident using SharePoint list for example
read news etc so having one device used my multiple people... is this how it is done or it is more better for user to use personal device also f1 license user don't have personal device. they share the device.

Comment: can they consume powerapps?

Comment: `can they consume powerapps?` -no, they can't

Answer (score 0):

### SharePoint Online Kiosk license

SharePoint Online Kiosk license is part of the [Microsoft 365 F1 Plan](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/f1?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab). It's very similar to [the SharePoint Online P1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans) license with a few limitations:

- You can't use it for SharePoint Online administration.
- This license won't include [OneDrive for Business](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/onedrive/onedrive-for-business).
- Since Microsoft Lists rely on OneDrive, they might not be available too.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this blog “[What is an Office 365 Kiosk licence?](https://digitalfirst.com/what-is-an-office-365-kiosk-licence/)”, Kiosk licenses are cheaper licenses for deskless workers.

PowerApps will not be included in this license. It needs a separate license with extra cost: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/

See the link here for comparison between different plans: [Optimize frontline impact with Microsoft 365.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/frontline#office-SKUChooser-0dbn8nt)